# How to fit/pack a graph into a $2D$ grid without destroying the connectivity?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, sparse-matrices

Given a graph like the one below, I try to pack/fit this graph into a fixed row $2D$ grid and use as few columns as possible. I can change the shape of the graph, but not the connectivity.

For example, the available grid has a fixed row size of $11$, and the original graph has a row size of $7$ as marked. Each $o$ represents a vertex and a vertex only connects to its adjacent neighbors. The black o are vertices on a row; every black $o$ only has one or two neighbors. The red $o$ are "bridges" connecting a different row of black $o$, which can have more than two neighbors.

There are two constraints for transformation:

1. The previous adjacent vertices are still adjacent.
2. Two nonadjacent vertices cannot be adjacent after transformation.

To simplify the question, I do not change the shape of the red vertices (although they may be transformed) and only change the shape of the black vertices.
[image]

A possible solution is shown below:
[image]

This problem can be thought of as using as few resources(columns) as to store the graph. The current solution is manually made.

I'm considering using a heuristic algorithm to solve it. For example, search for the chain of black $o$ that consume the fewest columns between the red parts without violating the constraints, but I think a better algorithm could exist for this problem.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @ShaunThanks for the advice. I have edited this question.

Comment: You're welcome! Thank you for editing! :)